# looping through a list of dictionaries to check if each dictionary contains a particular key

Tags: python, for-loop, typeerror

I am using python3, trying to loop through a list of dictionaries to check where each dictionary contains the key "retweeted_status." Currently, my code is:

```
for item in tweets_data:
if 'retweeted_status' in item:
    retweets2.append(item)
else: 
    pass
```

The type error I get is:

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-8c0e9225c623> in <module>()
      1 for item in tweets_data:
----> 2     if 'retweeted_status' in item:
      3         retweets2.append(item)
      4     else:
      5         pass 
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`.

`tweets_data` is a list containing tweets from a text file. To create this list, I opened and read the text file. For each line in the text file, I used json.loads(line) and saved the result from json.loads(line) to a variable. I then appended that saved result `tweets_data`.

I don't understand the error entirely. Does this mean that the item is not iterable?

The way I'm imagining this code to work is that it is iterating over my list of dictionaries (so, each item is a dictionary)...so why would the dictionary need to be iterable? Any explanation would be super helpful.

---

so, it turns out that for whatever reason my `tweets_data` was not completely a list of dictionaries and contained integers as people suggested below in the comments

Comment: [mcve] please. Looks like `list_of_dicts` contains integers...

Comment: I suspect you ``list_of_dicts`` is not a dictionary, but instead is an int. Try adding ``print type(list_of_dics)``. You should also ``print type(item)`` in the inner loop.

Comment: Please show the error message *with full traceback* in your question.  Which line is it on?  How is `list_of_dicts` constructed?  What type is `item`?

Comment: In other words: what you've written should work on a list of dictionaries.  So your input isn't a list of dictionaries.  Without more information that's about all anyone can tell you.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks. will edit.

Comment: @user590027 i've confirmed that type of `tweets_data` (formerly `list_of_dicts`) is a list.

Comment: @cdarke thanks. ive included full traceback. the type of `item` is dict.

Comment: @Alan Leuthard thanks, will continue to clarify.

Comment: In that case, `item` is an `int`, you need to look at `tweets_data` again.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what's wrong with your code without seeing all the values of variables you have in it.

However, this is a shorter and more "pythonic" way of doing what your want.

```
new_list = [dict for dict in list_of_dicts if "retweeted_status" in dict]
```

Comment: thanks for the more pythonic way. this also works, so i think that the problem is something about my structures of my `list_of_dicts` ...

Comment: Pythonic would not use dict as a variable name

Answer (score 0):

here's your answer.. I've put a dummy list of dictionaries for testing, your data very likely is structured differently, but the procedure should not be too different

```
new_list = []
list_of_dict = [{'name':'dict 1'},{'retweeted_status':True},{'name':'dict 3'}]
for item in list_of_dict:
  if 'retweeted_status' in item:
    new_list.append(item)

print new_list
```

Comment: this definitely works. so, i think that my problem must be something with the structure of my list of dictionaries. thanks!